# Get Hard disk serial Number

Tags: c#, hard-drive

I want to get hard disk serial number. How I can I do that?
I tried with two code but I am not getting

```
StringCollection propNames = new StringCollection();
ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
PropertyDataCollection  props = driveClass.Properties;
foreach (PropertyData driveProperty in props) 
{
    propNames.Add(driveProperty.Name);
}
int idx = 0;
ManagementObjectCollection drives = driveClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject drv in drives)
       {
          Label2.Text+=(idx + 1);
          foreach (string strProp in propNames)
           {
            //Label2.Text+=drv[strProp];
         Response.Write(strProp + "   =   " + drv[strProp] + "</br>");
          }
    }
```

In this one I am not getting any Unique Serial number.
And Second one is

```
string drive = "C";
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + drive + ":\"");
disk.Get();
Label3.Text = "VolumeSerialNumber="+ disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
```

Here I am getting `VolumeSerialNumber`. But it is not unique one. If I format the hard disk, this will change. How Can I get this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Hm, looking at your first set of code, I think you have retrieved (maybe?) the hard drive model. The serial # comes from `Win32_PhysicalMedia`.

Get Hard Drive model

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
    hd.Type  = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString(); 
    hdCollection.Add(hd);
   }
```

Get the Serial Number

```
 searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

   int i = 0;
   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
    // get the hard drive from collection
    // using index
    HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];

    // get the hardware serial no.
    if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
     hd.SerialNo = "None";
    else
     hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    ++i;
   }
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did you mean to post the same source twice?

Comment: I can't get around to compiling right now, but I did notice the post was from 2004, maybe it doesn't work on Vista/7? Just using the compiled exe, I actually just got an error "CLR20r3" on my Win7x64.

Comment: does it work if the user has no admin right...the code i have can fetch the info if he has admin rights..but if i try using same application from different user who has no admin  rights, fails to do that..

Comment: I tried this in WinXp SP3.. the wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] returns null.. any solutions?

Comment: **Why my test failed!(win7_X64 sp1)** The `Win32_PhysicalMedia`'s collection's count is bigger than the `Win32_DiskDrive`'s collection's count.Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Sprunth, I get all the connected Hard drivers, But how can I get the bootable one ?

Answer (score 12):

I have used the following method in a project and it's working successfully.

```
private string identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
//Return a hardware identifier
{
    string result = "";
    System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        //Only get the first one
        if (result == "")
        {
            try
            {
                result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

you can call the above method as mentioned below,

```
string modelNo = identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model");
string manufatureID = identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer");
string signature = identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature");
string totalHeads = identifier("Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads");
```

If you need a unique identifier, use a combination of these IDs.

Comment: thank you for reply.....after formatting the HD whether this same value will repeat?

Answer (score 8):

**There is a simple way for @Sprunth's answer.**

```
private void GetAllDiskDrives()
    {
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
        {
            HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
            hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
            hd.InterfaceType = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();
            hd.Caption = wmi_HD["Caption"].ToString();

            hd.SerialNo =wmi_HD.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();//get the serailNumber of diskdrive

            hdCollection.Add(hd);
        }

 }


public class HardDrive
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string InterfaceType { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "vol" shell command and parse serial from it's output, like this.
Works at least in Win7

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CheckHD
{
        class HDSerial
        {
            const string MY_SERIAL = "F845-BB23";
            public static bool CheckSerial()
            {
                string res = ExecuteCommandSync("vol");
                const string search = "Number is";
                int startI = res.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                if (startI > 0)
                {
                    string currentDiskID = res.Substring(startI + search.Length).Trim();
                    if (currentDiskID.Equals(MY_SERIAL))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public static string ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
            {
                try
                {
                    // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
                    // and "/c " as the parameters.
                    // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
                    // and then exit.
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

                    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
                    // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
                    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    // Do not create the black window.
                    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                    proc.Start();
                    // Get the output into a string
                    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    // Display the command output.
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Log the exception
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that will work splendidly on every language version of Windows. It's not like the text output of that command is different in a Russian, Japanese or Norwegian version of Windows compared to an English version, is it?

Comment: This give the serial of the logic unit, not the hard disk

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code that may help:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

string serial_number="";

foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
    serial_number = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
}

MessageBox.Show(serial_number);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As much effort obviously has gone into this answer, it might be difficult to get a grasp at if it's just code. It's usual to comment the solution with a few sentences. Please edit your answer and add some explanation. Also, remember to format the code before you post the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using  win32 api and std string in case you need your application to run on a OS with no CLR. I found it here on [github](https://gist.github.com/micjabbour/a2fbe50160862e6abe439c0b0769c3fb).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

//returns the serial number of the first physical drive in a std::string or an empty std::string in case of failure
//based on http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/10/26/get-physical-drive-serial-number-part-1/
std::string getFirstHddSerialNumber() {
    //get a handle to the first physical drive
    HANDLE h = CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return{};
    //an std::unique_ptr is used to perform cleanup automatically when returning (i.e. to avoid code duplication)
    std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, void(*)(HANDLE)> hDevice{ h, [](HANDLE handle){CloseHandle(handle); } };
    //initialize a STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY data structure (to be used as input to DeviceIoControl)
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY storagePropertyQuery{};
    storagePropertyQuery.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
    storagePropertyQuery.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
    //initialize a STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER data structure (to be used as output from DeviceIoControl)
    STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER storageDescriptorHeader{};
    //the next call to DeviceIoControl retrieves necessary size (in order to allocate a suitable buffer)
    //call DeviceIoControl and return an empty std::string on failure
    DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice.get(), IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &storagePropertyQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
        &storageDescriptorHeader, sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER), &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
        return{};
    //allocate a suitable buffer
    const DWORD dwOutBufferSize = storageDescriptorHeader.Size;
    std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pOutBuffer{ new BYTE[dwOutBufferSize]{} };
    //call DeviceIoControl with the allocated buffer
    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice.get(), IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &storagePropertyQuery, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
        pOutBuffer.get(), dwOutBufferSize, &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
        return{};
    //read and return the serial number out of the output buffer
    STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR* pDeviceDescriptor = reinterpret_cast<STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR*>(pOutBuffer.get());
    const DWORD dwSerialNumberOffset = pDeviceDescriptor->SerialNumberOffset;
    if (dwSerialNumberOffset == 0) return{};
    const char* serialNumber = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pOutBuffer.get() + dwSerialNumberOffset);
    return serialNumber;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string serialNumber = getFirstHddSerialNumber();
    if (serialNumber.empty())
        std::cout << "failed to retrieve serial number\n";
    else
        std::cout << "serial number: " << serialNumber << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a non WMI solution

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use it for copy protection and you need it to return always the same serial on one computer (of course as far as first hdd or ssd is not changed) I would recommend code below. For ManagementClass you need to add reference to System.Management. P.S. Without "InterfaceType" and "DeviceID" check that method can return serial of random disk or serial of USB flash drive which connected to pc right now.

```
    public static string GetSerial()
    {
        try
        {
            var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
            var moc = mc.GetInstances();
            var res = string.Empty;
            var resList = new List<string>(moc.Count);

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (mo["InterfaceType"].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty) == "USB")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    res = mo["SerialNumber"].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                    resList.Add(res);
                    if (mo["DeviceID"].ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Contains("0"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
                        {
                            return res;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            res = resList[0];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
            {
                return res;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is, download a dll from [here](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20ID%20programmer%27s%20DLL.html)

Then, add the dll to your project.

Then, add code:

```
[DllImportAttribute("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
public static extern String GetIDESerialNumber(byte DriveNumber);
```

Then, call the hard disk ID from where you need it

```
GetIDESerialNumber(0).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Note: go to properties of the dll in explorer and set "Build action" to "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Do you still have the dll?

Comment: The dll is available here: http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/free-download/free%20download.html

Answer (score 0):

Below a fully functional method to get hard disk serial number:

```
public string GetHardDiskSerialNo()
    {
        ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
        ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
        string result = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol)
        {
            result += Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: LogicalDisk serial is not the same that HardDisk Serial, you can try and see they differ

Answer (score 0):

I’m using this:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
private static string wmiProperty(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty){
  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM {wmiClass}")) {
   try {
                    IEnumerable<ManagementObject> objects = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>();
                    return objects.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue(wmiProperty)).FirstOrDefault().ToString().Trim();
                } catch (NullReferenceException) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```