# Retrieving disc serial id gives me different values using FSO or ManagementObject

Tags: c#, vb.net, disk, serial-number

I have an old vb application which retrieves the disk id using this code.

```
Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Dr As Scripting.Drive
Dim id_convertido As Long = 0
Dim sRutaAplicacion As String = Application.StartupPath
Dim Valor As Integer = sRutaAplicacion.IndexOf(":\")
If Valor <> -1 Then
    Dim RaizAplicacion As String
    RaizAplicacion = Mid(sRutaAplicacion, 1, Valor)
    For Each Dr In FSO.Drives
        If Dr.DriveLetter = RaizAplicacion Then
             Dim idDisco As String
             idDisco = Dr.SerialNumber
             id_convertido = (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(idDisco, 8))
             Return id_convertido
        End If
    Next
End If
```

I'm want to achieve the same functionality in c#, so I found this code:

```
string HDD = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, 1);
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + HDD + ":\"");
disk.Get();
return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
```

but i get different values. In my first code, "idDisco" is "876823094", but in c#, this value is "34434236".

Both are checking disk c:

Any clues?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my first code, "idDisco" is "876823094", but in c#, this value is "34434236"

It is the same value, 876823094 in hexadecimal notation is 0x34434236.  Use Calc.exe, View + Programmer to see this for yourself.  If you want to reproduce the same number that FSO gave you then you'll have to do the same thing it does and convert to base 10.  Like this:

```
string hex = disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
int value = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null);
string fso = value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084402/get-hard-disk-serial-number).

*The custom class `HardDrive` is used to store the retrieved information.*

**Get Hard Drive model**

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
    hd.Type  = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString(); 
    hdCollection.Add(hd);
}
```

**The (minimum) class HardDrive**

```
public class HardDrive
{
    public string Model { get; set }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Get the Serial Number**

```
searcher = new
ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

int i = 0;
foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
    // get the hard drive from collection
    // using index
    HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];

    // get the hardware serial no.
    if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
        hd.SerialNo = "None";
    else
        hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Class `HardDrive` added.

Comment: Alright, it works, but it doesn't solve my problem. The serial I get using this method is different from my 2 provided codes.

This is my problem, my program gets the "disk id" using the vb code I provided, in order to recognice if my program is used in several pc using the same login. I need to, in any way, manage to get the same id but using c#.

Comment: I made a .dll using the old vb code and it works so the problem is solved, thanks anyway!