# How to secure the Software license (Algorithm)

Tags: c#, windows, security, product-key

I am building an application which has a dynamic product key. I am trying to integrate these features

If user uninstall this app and again installs it then product key should not be void it should take the same product key for it.

I am going to take the mac address and stores it to a web server I am doing online verification so now the problem is that if the user changes the mac address(the network adapter) so key won't work.

So how can I make this valid? Is there any alternative to the MAC address which almost stays constant?

> A little pseudo code that describes how I would verify the product key:

```
if(mac remains same || any alternative method stays same)
{
    priduct_key = valid;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the MAC Address was a good thing to lock to?

Comment: HDD-identifier is also commonly used. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084402/get-hard-disk-serial-number). But in the end, I'm convinced that every application can be cracked, no matter how hard you try to protect it.

Comment: The hard disk serial is a worse idea.  A user should be able to upgrade their hardware without invalidating a software license.  If you are doing online validation, an abstract key you create could work.  Something like HD Serial or MAC Address assumes a single product and single version.

Comment: HDD-identifier is a good option

Comment: Thanks plutonix hard disk serial is a good idea it uses for digital forensic also