# Cannot get HDD Signature from Windows 10 in a C# application. But why?

Tags: c#, .net, offlineapps

Most desktops run this perfectly, but when it runs on a newly configured desktop like 7th generation clone pc, the whole application closes with an error stating it can not read HDD. But why? I use .net 4.5.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
{
   string SerialNo = wmi_HD.GetPropertyValue("Signature").ToString();

   if (SerialNo == "0" || SerialNo == "" || SerialNo == null)
   {
   }
   else
   {
      hdCollection.Add(SerialNo);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error you receive.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084402/get-hard-disk-serial-number. It is quite old, but the answer is saying that serial number comes from Win32_PhysicalMedia, not Win32_DiskDrive.

Comment: There hasn't any error. if i used these line of codes in my project. it works in every desktop without which desktops are built with new configuration. my team tested almost 5k+ desktop . 4th,5th,6th generation based desktop it runs perfectly. but when try to run in new 7th gen  configured with Windows 10. that's time automatically apps has been closed. this is the problem.

Comment: Did you try what @felbus suggested?

Comment: I am trying to get signature not serial number. signature number only get from Win32_DiskDrive.  @JonyAdamit

Answer (score 1):

You could write a fallback mechanism, to retrieve the signature from the registry.
It is located under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`. First 4 bytes in the Data values are the signature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. at last  i got a good advice from you. Thanks a lot.